# RxJs, how to handle workflow?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I work on an app on Angular 6 and I'm trying to learn how to use rxjs along the way.

Today I encounter a particular problem to resolve: `Handling workflow with Rxjs`.

I created an example in StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbstnw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

The ts

```
//app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { concat, interval, pipe, of } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, map, share, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  workflow$;
  documents$;
  images$;
  done$;

  constructor(){

    // We start with the workflow as a Base, then we use concat to run Observable in sequences
    this.workflow$ = concat(simulateMultipleReq(10, 'doc'), simulateMultipleReq(5, 'img'), of({done: 0}))
      .pipe(share());

    // 
    this.documents$ = this.workflow$.pipe(tokenFilter('doc'));
    this.images$ = this.workflow$.pipe(tokenFilter('img'))
    this.done$ = this.workflow$.pipe(tokenFilter('done'))
  }


}


function simulateMultipleReq(number, token){
  return interval(500)
    .pipe(takeWhile((x) => x < number), map((x) => {
      return {[token]: x}
    }))
}

function tokenFilter(token){
  return pipe(
    filter(getTokenValue(token)),
    map(getTokenValue(token)),
  )
}

function getTokenValue(token){
  return (x) => {
      return x[token] + 1
    }
}
```

The html

```
<!-- app.component.html -->
<div>{{documents$ | async}} / 10</div>
<div>{{images$ | async}} / 5</div>
<div *ngIf="done$ | async">
  Done sending data
</div>
```

So this example is working, but It does not seem right.

In short I use concat to run the Observables in sequence and for each one I wrap it in an object with a single key (which is used as a token).

And then when I want to subscribe I use this token to filter on my sequence.

Does this look good ? There is another way ?

Thanks, And if you have any question I'll be glad to answer it.

Comment: Please post relevant code here and not off-site.

Comment: @zero298 I updated it with the code inside the question